# Error R10 Boot Timeout, not binding to port

Tags: java, heroku

A few of us are working on this problem and have searched for hours to solve this problem. Currently my Procfile looks like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/GeodeTwitter2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dserver.port=$PORT
```

We're building a Twitter bot to tweet from a static file. It works for 90 seconds then stops. Here's an example of the error log:

```
2019-05-16T13:39:27.118323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-16T13:39:26.969000+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2019-05-16T13:39:26.969118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-05-16T13:39:27.091840+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

We're using Spring Boot with Maven. When run locally from Spring Boot, the app works and tweets indefinitely.

Please let me know any other information that I should provide.

Comment: I guess you would get better support on Stackoverflow.com instead of SFSE

Comment: @Raul Heroku is on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

A web server (those set as "web") are expected to host a website. You must call `listen()` within 90 seconds, or the process will terminate. Instead, you will want to make a "[worker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing)", which are used to perform background tasks.